# Obtaining starting View from Handler of the command

Tags: view, command, handler, jface, treeviewer

I have a certain View.

In this view there is a TreeViewer.

When I right-click one element of the tree, I open the contextual menu that trigger the command "rename".

In the HANDLER of this command, how can I obtain the ID of the view of the selected element?

Is it possible to get it?

Thanks very much to everyone will answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`HandlerUtil`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/handlers/HandlerUtil.html). In this example, since you right-click on an element in a view, it should become active and you can use

```
HandlerUtil.getActivePartId(e);
```